Calculate PnL with vectorization
I have a dataframe with prices and Entry Exit Signals and want to calculate pnl without for looping the dataframe:
If Signal == "Entry (short)" I will short A and buy B, vice versa for "Entry (long)". Signal == "Exit (short) closes out "Entry (short)" and vice versa for "Exit (long)" all in chronological order so corresponding Exits come after corresponding Entry.
e.g.
price_df[price_df["signal"].str.contains("E")] #filtered and show how entry exits are ordered

              A        B        A/B Z score    Signal
2021-04-19  4926.1  148.2251    2.187012    Entry (short)
2021-05-31  4357.7  159.8565    0.030637    Exit (short)
2022-01-06  4658.9  137.4595    2.139689    Entry (short)
2022-02-07  3624.1  123.2928    -0.018995   Exit (short)

Now, between each pair of entry and exit will be either -1 corresponding to Entry (short) or 1 corresponding to Entry (long).
e.g.
              A        B        A/B Z score    Signal
2021-04-19  4926.1  148.2251    2.187012    Entry (short)
2021-04-20  4726.9  145.8136    1.880473    -1
2021-04-21  4488.9  140.3698    1.715539    -1
...
2021-05-27  4333.4  157.0219    0.165915    -1
2021-05-28  4440.3  157.4703    0.417588    -1
2021-05-31  4357.7  159.8565    0.030637    Exit (short)

Goal
I want to create a column p&L that calculates:
for Entry/Exit (short): (B.pct_change() - A.pct_change())/2
for Entry/Exit (long): (-B.pct_change() + A.pct_change())/2
So far I'm using a for loop to keep track of position etc but vectorization would be much faster...

Assuming percent change is calculated between entry and corresponding exit, you can use the following vectorized approach
import pandas as pd


data = {
    "date": ["2021-04-19", "2021-05-31", "2021-06-02", "2021-08-23", "2022-01-06", "2022-02-07", "2022-08-18", "2022-12-23"],
    "A": [4926.1, 4357.7, 4658.9, 3624.1, 1232.3, 6343.3, 3214.5, 2122.2],
    "B": [148.2251, 159.8565, 137.4595, 123.2928, 234.1234, 543.6543, 547.8976, 765.4908],
    "Signal": ["Entry (short)", "Exit (short)", "Entry (long)", "Exit (long)", "Entry (short)", "Exit (short)", "Entry (long)", "Exit (long)"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# sort by date
df = df.sort_values(by='date')

# keep entry/exit signal rows
df = df[df['Signal'].str.startswith('E')]

# calculate percent changes between entry and corresponding exit
df['A_pct_change'] = df['A'].pct_change()
df['B_pct_change'] = df['B'].pct_change()


# calculate PnL
df['PnL'] = np.where(
    df['Signal'] == 'Exit (short)', (df['B_pct_change'] - df['A_pct_change'])/2,
    np.where(
        df['Signal'] == 'Exit (long)', (df['A_pct_change'] - df['B_pct_change'])/2, np.NAN
    )
)


P.S. I have excluded rows with signal=-1 since they're not relevant for the calculation
